# Need Angular 8 canActivate to return Observable<boolean> of a Subject

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs

So I have an Angular 8 application that uses cookies to handle authentication (Laravel server using Laravel Sanctum). Because I am using cookies and I dont store any user data/tokens in localStorage, I have to fetch the current user from my server every time my app initializes using a stored cookie.

auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService {

    public readonly INITIAL_PATH = '/app/dashboard';
    public readonly LOGIN_PATH = '/login';

    private loggedUserSubject: Subject<User>;
    public loggedUser: Observable<User>;

    constructor(
        private apiService: ApiService,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router,
        private csrfService: CsrfService,
    ) {
        this.loggedUserSubject = new Subject;
        this.loggedUser = this.loggedUserSubject.asObservable();

        this.getCurrentUser().subscribe(); // Initial call to server to get current user
    }

    ...

    getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${config.authUrl}/user`)
            .pipe(
                tap(user => {
                    this.loggedUserSubject.next(user);
                }),
                share()
            );
    }

    isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loggedUser.pipe(
            tap(user => {
                console.log('logged user: ', user);
            }),
            map(user => !!user),
            catchError(() => of(false)),
        )
    }

    ...
}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _authService: AuthService
    ) { }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this._authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
            tap(isLoggedIn => {
                if (isLoggedIn) {
                    this._router.navigate(['/app/dashboard']);
                }
            }),
            map(isLoggedIn => !isLoggedIn)
        );
    }
}
```

Whenever my AuthGuard is hit, it has to call `AuthService.isLoggedIn()` to return a `Observable<boolean>` of whether or not a User is in memory. The problem is, I am returning a Subject which may or may not have already emitted a value because I have to make an asynchronous request to my server to get the current user initially. I cant use a BehaviourSubject because canActivate returns the first emitted value... which I wont know until the server responds.

How do I set this up to make AuthGuard.canActivate() wait for my service to provide the authenticated User?

Comment: Try changing the guard to return the Boolean value. AFAIK, If you return the Observable, it returns the Observable and doesn't wait for the Observable to complete. If you return the Boolean, it will automatically wait for the Observable to complete so it can return the Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First I changed the loggedUserSubject from a Subject to a BehaviorSubject with an initial value of undefined (I dont know if that made any difference TBH). I then had to add a filter operator the isLoggedIn() Observable to return only the first *defined* value (User if logged in, null if not). Otherwise its returning the first emitted value, which was undefined before.

auth.service.ts

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.getCurrentUser().pipe(
        filter(user => user !== undefined),
        map(user => {
            return !!user;
        }),
    );
}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
        first(),
        tap(isLoggedIn => {
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                this._router.navigate(['/app/dashboard']);
            }
        }),
        map(isLoggedIn => !isLoggedIn)
    );
}
```